# Using a string as a coordinate fails

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmath

When I use `\pgfresult` to get a node label in a `\foreach`, I have no problem.

However, I can't seem to get the syntax right to create a coordinate with the same method.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\pinlabel{{"SCL","SDA"}}
        \foreach \x in {0,1}{
        \node at (\x,0){\pgfmathparse{\pinlabel[\x]}\pgfmathresult};  %<==== works!

        %\node at (\x,0){\pgfmathparse{\pinlabel[\x]}\pgfmathresult} coordinate ({\pgfmathparse{\pinlabel[\x]}\pgfmathresult});  %<====== doesnt't work

    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The commented line fails with: incomplete `\iffalse`; all text was ignored after line 15.

I've tried doing the parse earlier, and just using the `\pgfmathresult` alone, but that also fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an expansion issue. In imprecise and colloquial terms: if the parser sees all the "junk" before the closing brackets, it does not know how to deal with it. But there is also no reason to do the expansion in the brackets. One way, certainly not unique, is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\pinlabel{{"SCL","SDA"}}
        \foreach \X in {0,1}{  
        \path   \pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{\pinlabel[\X]}
            \xdef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}}
        node at (\X,0) {\tmp} coordinate (\tmp);  
    }
    \draw[blue] (SCL) -- ++(1,1); %test
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you do not necessarily have to do the computation of the pinlabel while you are constructing the path, you can simply perform it beforehand using `\pgfmathsetmacro`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\pinlabel{{"SCL","SDA"}}
  \foreach \X in {0,1}{  
    \pgfmathsetmacro\tmp{\pinlabel[\X]}
    \node at (\X,0) {\tmp} coordinate (\tmp);  
  }
  \draw[blue] (SCL) -- ++(1,1); %test
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or even more efficiently, because the label doesn't change during one loop iteration, directly evaluate it as part of the `\foreach` statement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\pinlabel{{"SCL","SDA"}}
  \foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \tmp using {\pinlabel[\X]}] in {0,1}{  
    \node at (\X,0) {\tmp} coordinate (\tmp);  
  }
  \draw[blue] (SCL) -- ++(1,1); %test
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\pgfmathsetmacro\tmp{\pinlabel[\X]}` be much easier?

Comment: @HenriMenkehe I tried that, and had much the same issue.  In fact, that failure led me down this path.  I'm not sure why it didn't work ---  perhaps that should have been my question!

Comment: I think you at least have to pass through  parse.

Comment: @HenriMenke It might, I have not gone that way because I was under the impression that the OP wants to do these things "on the fly". That's why set everything up in the path command.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I added the solution I was thinking about.  @ marmot I hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: Can you explain the [evaluate=\X as \tmp using {\pinlabel[\X]}]?  This seems to be what I was missing!

Comment: @HenriMenke Could you please answer Scott's question?

Comment: @ScottSeidman It does the same as the second code, both are in fact from Henri. As Henri explained, it's just a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Array management in Ti*k*Z is very clumsy, in my opinion.

Here's an implementation using `expl3` that doesn't require `\pgfmathparse` juggling.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setarray}{mm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = items
  \seq_new:c { l_seidman_array_#1_seq }
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn { l_seidman_array_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getitem}{mm}
 {% #1 = array name, #2 = index
  \seq_item:cn { l_seidman_array_#1_seq } { #2 + 1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setarray{pinlabel}{SCL,SDA} % can also be set locally

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,1}{
  \node at (\x,0) {\getitem{pinlabel}{\x}};
  \node at (\x,1) {\getitem{pinlabel}{\x}}
        coordinate (\getitem{pinlabel}{\x});
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Calling it clumsy is actually acknowledging its existence :)

Comment: @percusse The main issue, in my opinion, is the idea of allowing different data types into arrays.

Comment: Indeed it is just a comma separated container with no structure.

Comment: @percusse Actually no: entries enclosed in `"..."` are treated as strings, otherwise they're considered numbers. I'm not sure what applications need this.